# VAO problems with bind

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo

Help to find the error. 
I suppose it is wrong to bind. In "display" I used VBO - all works fine.
But when I used VAO - i get black screen.

```
void createVAO(GLuint *_vId, GLuint *_cId, GLuint *_tId, GLuint *_vao) {
glGenVertexArrays(1, _vao);
glBindVertexArray(*_vao);

glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, *_vId );
glVertexPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0 );

glBindVertexArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); }


void createVBO(GLuint *_vId, GLuint *_cId, GLuint *_tId) {
glGenBuffers(1, _vId);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, *_vId);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(XYZ) * cubeVerticesCount, cubePositions, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); }


void display() {
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0, 0, -800);
glRotatef(rotate.angle_x, 1, 0, 0);
glRotatef(rotate.angle_y, 0, 1, 0);
glScalef(zoom,zoom,zoom);

// VAO - dont work
glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, 0, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
glBindVertexArray(0);

// VBO - work
//glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
//glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vId );
//glVertexPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0 );
//glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, cubeVerticesCount);
//glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

calculateFPS();
glutSwapBuffers(); }
```

Full source code.
http://codepad.org/I87AxDl4

I'm sorry for a lot of unnecessary code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VAO doesn't have an [index buffer in it](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers). `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` is *part* of the VAO's state. So when you bind a VAO, what's bound to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` will *change* to that VAO's element array buffer.

You need to bind the element buffer in `createVAO`, after binding your VAO (but before unbinding it).

Comment: Did I understand correctly? I also need to create an array of indexes, and to bind it?

Comment: @ObiSan: That's what `glDrawElements` *does*: it [draws with an array of indices](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification). Therefore, if you want to draw with an array of indices, then you need an array of indices to draw with. If you don't want to draw with an array of indices, why are you using `glDrawElements`?

Comment: Found a good tutorial, but do not read it carefully. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your are using `glDrawElements` without any `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`in VAO

You probably want to use `glDrawArrays`, the same way your `// VBO - work` does